# java- Is it possible to pass a javascript variable to a java function?

Tags: javascript, java

I am working on JSP web page and on an input text where user can select a date on the textbox. I need to retrieve that value and update it on my database by calling a Java method that I created.

So the input looks like below:

```
End Date:<input class="txtEndDate" type="text" id="txtEndDate" name="txtEndDate" readonly/><br><br>
```

And my Javascript function as shown:

```
 // function to save data into table
    function save() {


        var enddate = $('#txtEndDate').val();

        <%

  // function to update the value
         fileFacade.insert_update(id,uniquecode,date,//enddate??);

        %>


    }
```

Now I know javascript is client side while Java is back end part but I need to pass `enddate` to the function parameter. Is there any way I could accomplish this?

EDIT:

updateURL.jsp:

```
<%@ page import="java.sql.Date" %>
<%@ page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat" %>

<%@ page import="java.util.Locale" %>
<%@include file="../../../WEB-INF/jspf/mcre.jspf" %>
<%@include file="../../../WEB-INF/jspf/session.jspf"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>


</head>
<body>

<%
    long fileID = Long.parseLong(request.getParameter("id"));
    String uniquecode=request.getParameter("uniquecode");
    String startdt=request.getParameter("startdate");
    String enddate=request.getParameter("enddate");







    int enablestatus= Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("enable"));

    fileFacade.insert_update(fileID,uniquecode,startdt,enddate,enablestatus);



%>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Take a  look at  ajax

Comment: "Java is mainly back end part" - Java is backend _only_ (except you're talking about Applets which I doubt)

Comment: hope [this](https://javapapers.com/ajax/getting-started-with-ajax-using-java/) helps. it is bout how to make ajax calls from java

Comment: By the way, you might be interested in the [*Vaadin*](http://www.Vaadin.com/) web app framework. On-the-fly at runtime, Vaadin auto-generates all the HTML, CSS, JavaScript, AJAX, DOM, WebSocket, and Push code needed to render the client-side user-interface (in web browser) of your server-side app written in pure Java.

Answer (score 2):

You can call ajax method and update you data via API

follow code below:

```
fuction updateData(id, uniquecode) {
  var enddate = $('#txtEndDate').val();
  var radioEnableStatus = = $("input[name='radioEnableStatus']:checked").val();
  $.ajax({

    url : 'API URL',
    type : 'POST',
    data : {
        'id' : id,
        'uniquecode': uniquecode,
        'enddate': enddate,
        'radioEnableStatus': radioEnableStatus
    },
    dataType:'json',
    success : function(data) {              
        alert('Data: '+data);
    },
    error : function(request,error)
    {
        alert("Request: "+JSON.stringify(request));
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190663/discussion-on-answer-by-devratna-java-is-it-possible-to-pass-a-javascript-varia).

Comment: i'm in chatbox now